# How to get the regional maximum or minimum of raster data by using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

If I have Mean sea surface pressure data in raster format, is it possible for PostGIS to look for regional maximum or minimum? So that I can locate the L or H as the chart shown below? (image source: NOAA)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that your air pressure data is similar to terrain height data you can use DEM tools. By reading about the DEM tools in http://postgis.net/docs/RT_reference.html it looks like PostGIS has the tools for getting rather far but because I am not familiar with them I made a demonstration with GDAL and QGIS.

When you search the local minimum and maximum values you are looking for points where the pressure is not changing when you move to any direction. They are like hill tops or bottoms of the valleys.

Take some raw raster data

[image]

Compute a slope raster with gdaldem slope tool http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html. Corresponding PostGIS function is "ST_Slope" http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Slope.html.

```
gdaldem slope -p test_dem.tif test_slope.tif
```

[image]

Select flat areas with slope < 1%. Big flat things are lakes but we have a closer look at one hill.

[image]

Red arrows show that we did find the hill top. Blue arrows show that we did find other flat areas too but perhaps your air pressure measurements are rather smooth and behave better.

[image]

But is the local extreme peak or bottom? Select an area around it and compare with average value. If average is lower you found the peak, otherwise the bottom. The PostGIS raster function "ST_Mean4ma" http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Mean4ma.html feels good for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the image it looks like you would like to know where are the blue "H" and red "L" characters. I suppose that you could get the best result by applying some Optical Character Recognition tool. However, I was able to make something partially successful with GDAL.

The blue "H" in the attached gif file is pure blue RGB 0-0-255 and the corresponding palette value is #5. The color or red "L" is RGB 255-17-17 and in the palette it is #27.

Gdal_polygonize.py http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html can be used for converting area with uniform pixel values into polygons in a vector file.

```
gdal_polygonize.py color.gif -f "ESRI Shapefile" color.shp
```

Open the resulting shapefile with GIS program like OpenJUMP or QGIS and select vectors with palette value "5".

[image]

Ok, blue "H"s have been selected but something else too. Because same font have been used for the whole map the probably letters are rather similar after they have been vectorised. So they should have about the same area and perimeter. You can play a bit and test if this approach could give some useful results.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I am sorry that you misunderstood my question. What I mean is that, by using raw raster data, find out the min and max of a region. There are no character H and L in the image. But thanks for your effort!

Comment: Ok. Do you simply want to find the absolute min and max values inside a region or are you interested in local max min values? Like do you want to find the location of all points presented as H and L letters in your example map of just the ultimate H and L?

Comment: yes. I am interested in local max or min value.

If it is global max and min, I can only get 1 max and 1 min. It is not what I want.